# CVS server configuration

Tags: configuration, cvs, tortoisecvs

I have a CVS repository on Freebsd and a ssh access. When I use putty client connection is ok.

CVSROOT=:/labs/cvs
CVS_RSH=ssh

But when I try to do checkout with TortoiseCVS

CVSROOT :ext:root@server:/labs/cvs

error occurs:

cvs commit: warning: unrecognized response `Access denied' from cvs server
   cvs commit: warning: unrecognized response`No supported authentication methods left to  try!' from cvs server
   cvs [commit aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)

Error, CVS operation failed

What's wrong? What must I do for successful checkout?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `:ssh:` instead of `:ext:` as Tortoise uses CVSNT internally which supports SSH natively. It should be possible to get it to work with `:ext:` too but usually it's not worth the hassle. BTW: CVSNT's SSH support is also built upon PuTTY/Plink.

Comment: This was a problem for me when using TortoiseCVS on Windows, and doing a checkout from a Linux server onto a mapped drive. It worked fine if I navigated via My Network Places, but with a mapped drive, it gave the error mentioned above. Changing the Protocol from :ext: to :ssh: fixed it! Thanks!